# Monitoring Memory usage of EC2 Windows Server- There is no "CloudWatch log" option in EC2Config anymore

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm gonna monitor Memory usage of an EC2 windows server R2 2012. I have installed the latest version of EC2Config which is 4.9.2061 by downloading it from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_Install.html

I have attached this role to the server:

```
 {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAccessToSSM",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then proceed with the following document for configuring json file, etc:

http://blog.krishnachaitanya.ch/2016/03/monitor-ec2-memory-usage-using-aws.html

The IAM user that is setup in json file has complete access.

The problem is that when I open EC2ConfigServiceSetting to enable CloudWatch logs, there is NO CloudWatch Logs there. It seems they have removed that option in the new version.

[image]

I would be thankfull if anyone can give a suggestion for monitoring MemoryUsage of EC2 Windows server.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok not to see that checkbox.

Try restarting the "Amazon SSM Agent" service and then the "Ec2Config" service.

Then, wait to see if your metrics appears.
The other config to check is the `config.xml` in the same folder as the JSON, make sure the CloudWatch plugin is Enabled.